# ¿Cómo hacer un SELECT con restricciones dependiendo que seleccione el usuario? c#

Tags: c#

Como andan? me encuentro en la siguiente Screen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el usuario seleccionaría que muestre las ventas de todos los vendedores/clientes, o de un cliente en especifico, o de un vendedor en especifico.

Al darle click en generar informe, me lleva a otro form donde tengo el ReportViewer, con su dataset y el report.rdlc correspondiente.

Mi duda es: Como hacer estas consultas? con varios dataset y diferentes Forms ??? O se pueden manipular los DataSet, (que se ejecuten dependiendo que selecciona el usuario) o asi tener 3 o mas DataSet que se ejecutaría dependiendo lo que el usuario quiera, con un solo Form con su ReportViewer.

Por ejemplo: Supongamos que tengo un DataSet con el siguiente SQL:

```
select FechaHora, COUNT(idVenta) from venta
group by FechaHora
```

Este se debería de ejecutar, cuando el cliente seleccione todos los clientes y todos los vendedores.

Para los otros SQL, generaría otros dataset ??? Se puede poner en un reportViewer varios dataset y que se ejecuten dependiendo que seleccione el usuario??

Espero que me hallan entendido, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad un `DataSet` es un set (*conjunto*) de datos (*Data*) que permite contener dentro varias tablas. Estos objetos se llaman `DataTable`s.
Entonces, podrías tener un único DataSet y allí agregar todos los DataTable que quieras. En tu caso, entiendo necesitarías 3, uno por cada query distinta.
Y así sólo estarías teniendo 1 Form para generar los datos (a través de la ejecución de las queries) y enviando un único DataSet al ReportViewer.

Por ejemplo, podrías hacer así:

```
DataTable dtTabla1 = new DataTable();
DataTable dtTabla2 = new DataTable();
DataTable dtTabla3 = new DataTable();

DataSet dsTablas = new DataSet();
dsTablas.Tables.Add(dtTabla1);
dsTablas.Tables.Add(dtTabla2);
dsTablas.Tables.Add(dtTabla3);
```

Así agregas las 3 tablas al DataSet.

Comment: Gracias Matias! Entendi bien lo que me explicas, pero se me presentan otros problemas. Voy a necesitar otra ayuda por otro lado. Ya que aca no puedo seguir preguntando. Gracias!